# About mysql regex,how do I search and return string use mysql regex

Tags: mysql, regex

My table filed's value is `"<script type="text/javascript"src="http://localhost:8080/db/widget/10217EN/F"></script>"`,

I want to analyse this string and fetch the id 10217,how to do use mysql regex?
I know python regex group function can return the id 10217,but i'm not familiar with mysql regex.

Please help me,Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL regular expressions do not support subpattern extraction. You will probably have better luck iterating over all of the rows in your database and storing the results in a new column.

Comment: I will add a new column to resolve this question,thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't use MySQL's REGEXP for substring retrieval; it is designed for use in WHERE clauses and is limited to returning 0 or 1 to indicate failure or success at a match.

Since your pattern is pretty well defined, you can probably retrieve the id with a query that uses SUBSTR and LOCATE. It will be a bit of a mess since SUBSTR wants the start index and the *length* of the substring (it would be easier if it took the end index). Perhaps you could use TRIM to chop off the unwanted trailing part.

Comment: The method:SELECT SUBSTR('<script type="text/javascript"src="http://localhost:8080/db/widget/10217EN/F"></script>',LOCATE('widget/','<script type="text/javascript"src="http://localhost:8080/db/widget/10217EN/F"></script>')+7,5) id，can fetch id,but is very foolish,I will add a new column to resolve this quesion.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This query get the Id from the field

SELECT substring_index(SUBSTRING_INDEX(testvar,'/',-3),'EN',1) from testtab;

where as testtab - is table name , testvar - is field name

inner substring get string starts with last 3 / which is

mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(testvar,'/',-3) from testtab;

+----------------------------+
| SUBSTRING_INDEX(testvar,'/',-3) |
+----------------------------+
| 10217EN/F">       |
| 10222EN/F">       |
+----------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

outer substring get

mysql> SELECT substring_index(SUBSTRING_INDEX(testvar,'/',-3),'EN',1) from testtab;

+----------------------------------------------------+
| substring_index(SUBSTRING_INDEX(testvar,'/',-3),'EN',1) 
|
+----------------------------------------------------+
| 10217                                              |
| 10222                                              |
+----------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: The SQL called frequently.So I need add a new column.Thank you.